# Why does `utf8.Valid()` consider some valid UTF-8 code as invalid?

Tags: go, utf-8

```
$ cat main.go

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    str, err := ioutil.ReadFile(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }
    fmt.Println(utf8.Valid([]byte(str)))
}
$ go run main.go <(echo $'\xed\xa0\xb5')
false
```

`utf8.Valid()` says '\xed\xa0\xb5' is invalid.

- `\xed`: `11101101`
- `\xa0`: `10100000`
- `\xb5`: `10110101`

But there are the three bytes in binary format. `111xxxxx` means it is a three bytes characters. According to the table on the wiki page, the following two bytes should valid.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Does anybody know why `utf8.Valid()` shows the three byte character as invalid UTF-8 character?

Answer (score 7):

As per the [codepage layout table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout) on Wikipedia, while the hex sequence `\xed\xa0\xb5` follows the encoding rules for the codepoint at `0xd835`, it is considered invalid as it matches the codepoint reserved for surrogate halves in UTF-16. When looking at the [codepoint table](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/D000-DFFF#endnote_SURROGATE) for Unicode, you'll see that the codepoints from `0xD800` to `0xDFFF` are all unassigned and marked as "explicitly invalid in UTF-8".

> Unicode and ISO/IEC 10646 do not assign actual characters to any of the code points in the D800–DFFF range — these code points only have meaning when used
> in surrogate pairs. Hence an individual code point from a surrogate pair does not represent a character, is invalid unless used in a surrogate pair, and is
> unconditionally invalid in UTF-32 and UTF-8 (if strict conformance to the standard is applied).